# Produce random numbers in pairs with java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am developing a memory game in java as my homework. I want to produce random numbers 1 between number of boxes with pairs.

```
public void GenerateBoxesGrid(JPanel jp){
       jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,4));
       for (int i = 0; i < numberofboxes; i++) {
            int num = generator.nextInt(5);
            button[i] = new JToggleButton();
            button[i].setText(Integer.toString(num));
            button[i].setSize(1,1);
            jp.add(button[i]);
            button[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
            button[i].setVisible(true);
```

The generator object is generating random numbers but without pairs.For example when user wants 6 boxes it should be 1,1,2,2,3,3 on screen.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: thanks for your feedback i will consider all of your important comments :).

Comment: Do you need further information here? You know, its like two days, no upvotes nowhere, no accept. Please dont leave questions to rot here. When you got what you need: accept and move on. if things are unclear, ask for clarification, get things sorted out, then accept and move on ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't want "random numbers in pairs".

There are only 3 "random" numbers in 1,1,2,2,3,3: 1, 2, and 3.

In other words: the most simplistic approach would be to generate *three* random numbers, and use each number twice. There is no need to "pair" anything. Just create *n* random numbers, and simply create *two* buttons for each of those numbers. Of course, to make creating your buttons easier, you could do this:

- create a list/array with *n* random numbers
- create a **second** list with *n* slots, a copy of the first list
- now **shuffle** the second list
- finally: write your loop, and within your loop, for each row, you pick one entry from each list

I think the above approach is the "easiest" way to generate such a table of "pairs" that are randomly placed across that table. ( a memory game where all pairs are in the same row isn't really interesting, you know )

And hint: the part that you forgot about so far: you should make sure that those *n* random numbers are different. Or to be precise: you should consider if you want to allow 1,1,2,2,1,1 ... or not.

Finally: if you want to do a "real" memory puzzle, then things go like this:

- you create n/2 random numbers, you put each value into your initial list *twice*
- you shuffle the initial list
- now: you iterate that initial list and populate *whatever* grid with *n* members you can think of (could be n/2 rows with 2 columns, or n rows with just 1 column for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Integer> generateNumbers(int count) {
  List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.range(1, count + 1 )
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
  numbers.addAll(numbers);
  Collections.shuffle(numbers);
  return numbers;
}
```

1) Generate range of numbers

2) Double all generated numbers

3) Shuffle in a random way

4) Iterate and draw cells with numbers from array